# Use clearAbortBroadcast() mehod outside onReceive in Android BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an Android app to block incoming SMS messages and release them after do some process.

What I want to do is, When a SMS received that message need to be blocked and push it to an online server. After that an administrator can view those messages pushed to the server through a website and he/she can approve or reject. If the admin approve the message it need to be release to the phone inbox else discard the message.

I complete everything except one thing. What I did is after the message pushed to the server a scheduled timer task will be started and read the online server in every 5min and check weather the message is approved. I'm using a "BroadcastReceiver" to track incoming messages and I know that to relese a blocked message I should use "clearAbortBroadcast()" method before "onReceive" method end. BUT my timer act as a thread. So if I call "clearAbortBroadcast()" method inside the timer the "onReceive" method is already finished execution and message doesn't get released.

Can some one help me to overcome this problem.

my BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

// run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
// timer handling
private Timer mTimer = null;
public static long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 15000;
int id;
Context context;

SmsReceiver sr;

GetMsgStatus status;
Bundle bundle;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //this stops notifications to others
    this.abortBroadcast();


    this.context = context;

    //create a instance of GetMsgStatus class
    status = new GetMsgStatus(context);

    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    bundle = intent.getExtras();   
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String from = null;
    String to = null;
    String msg= null;
    String str = "";            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            msg = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n"; 
        }
        System.out.println("from "+from);
        System.out.println("msg "+msg);
        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Received : ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
        mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        to = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();

        //push msg to the server
        SendMsgToServer send = new SendMsgToServer(context, to, from, msg);

        //get the msg id of the pushed msg
        id = send.getId();

     // cancel if already existed
        if(mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        } else {
            // recreate new
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }

        // schedule task
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);

        }
}

class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {               
                status.getDataFromServer(id);
                //if status is 0 means msg rejected
                if(status.getStatus()==0)
                {
                    mTimer.cancel();
                }

                //if status is 1 means msg approved
                else if(status.getStatus()==1)
                {
                    sr.clearAbortBroadcast();
                    mTimer.cancel();
                }

                //pending
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("pending");
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It might help if you share some code.

Answer (score 0):

A BroadcastReceiver is not supposed to live that much, so you can't depend on clearAbortBroadcast().

In your case I think your flow would be:

1. Receive broadcast and send to server.
2. Abort the broadcast and delete SMS from cellphone (user should be warned about this)
3. Wait for approval from server.
4. If approved, save the message to SMS and notify the user.

I don't think this kind of censor is good, but you may have your reasons, just make sure the user who install this knows what it does.

Comment: I would suggest use Google Cloud Message to send the approved SMS text inside an a Notification from Server to Phone. It avoids the "pooling" , and 5 mins "pooling" is a heavy battery drainer.